# Using part of Text to control redirect using Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

In our project, there are different urls assigned to different categories of product. If the product category is Cat1, click on edit button should take the user to the Cat1 page, and Cat2 should take the user to Cat2 page. However these categories are in a dynamic table so we can not use a fix reference for the edit buttons, and I am trying to make it dynamic. Below is my code snippet:

```
it('should take the user to appropriate page', function () {
    expect(globalVariables.Edit_Button_1.isDisplayed());

    // get rows
    var row_1 = globalVariables.tableData_Dashboard.all(by.tagName("tr")).get(1);

    // get cell values
    var cells = row_1.all(by.tagName("td"));

    var Cetegory = cells.get(3).getText().then(function (GL) {
        // console.log(GL)
        return GL;
    });

    globalVariables.Edit_Button_1.click();


    browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(globalVariables.Edit_Button_1), 25000, 'Edit button is not disappearing yet');

    if (Cetegory.endsWith('Cat1')){
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEndWith("Cat1");
    }
    else {
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEndWith("Cat2")
    }
```

The tests fails with the log "  Failed: Cetegories.endsWith is not a function ..

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cetegory` is a promise, not a string. Thus it does has function `endsWith`. You need to consume the promise eventual value in `then()` as following.

```
Cetegory.then(function(_Cetegory){
    if (_Cetegory.endsWith('Cat1')){
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEndWith("Cat1");
    }
    else {
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEndWith("Cat2")
    }
})
```